# What does '\' mean in a JavaScript function parameter?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have been asked to document some code. Some javascript functions pass parameters like

```
onclick='showhide(<%#String.Format("\"#customer{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex) %>);'
```

1. What is the purpose of "\" in the code?
2. Are they some special kind of escape characters? Would the code fail if we remove them?

Comment: What server side scripting language is this? VB or C#?

Comment: <%#String.Format("\"#customer{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex) %> - it looks like C# server side code, but not Javascript.

Comment: Hi that is C# but the function is javascript, I think its passing some parameters, I just want to know what is the function for including '/' in the function parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are 'escaping' the quotation marks, so they can be included in the string. Otherwise they would be confused with the start/end quotation marks of the string.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't look like (pure) JavaScript, but instead like some other language that *produces* JavaScript code (probably ASP.NET):

Assuming that `<%# %>` is that languages code to insert the result of the contained statement into the text, this means that the result of

```
String.Format("\"#customer{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex)
```

will be written between the closing and the opening parenthesis of the function call.

This means that the escape character `\` isn't use in JavaScript here, but in the host language (probably C# or VB.NET). The meaning is probably the same as in JavaScript, 'though: it escapes the double-quote to allow it to be represented inside a string literal.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that `\"` is probably used in the server-side language, not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is the purpose of "\" in the code ?

Seems like escape sequences to me. Assuming that this is C# code, the string in your code:

```
"\"#customer{0}\""
```

is interpreted by the compiler as:

```
"#customer{0}"
```

(this **INCLUDES** the double quotes)

When this is response.written, the output will become:

```
onclick='showhide("#customer_1234");'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an escape character.

In this case it is escaping the " character.

Answer (score 1):

It is an escape sequence used in the above code.

When written in string `\"` is equivalent to `"`. i.e.,

`<%#String.Format("\"#customer{0}\"",Container.DataItemIndex) %>`

would render something like this if `DataItemIndex` is `9`

`"#customer9"`